# How to convert a scipy sparse matrix to pyspark dataframe without calling toPandas or todense?

Tags: numpy, pyspark, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a big `scipy.sparse` matrix `data_transformed` of the following size:

```
<101772x69768 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 17317540 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

And I'd like to convert it to `pyspark.DataFrame` without collecting it on driver. My tries:

1. Batch processing by rows
   `spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(np.array(data_transformed[:5].todense())))`
   but it seems that `spark` is having trouble in inferring a schema for this many columns...
2. Batch processing by columns

```
data_transformed_sp_list = []
for i in tqdm(range(0, data_transformed.shape[1])):
    data_transformed_sp_list.append(
        spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(np.array(data_transformed[:, i].todense())))
    )
```

but it's also not feasible as per `tqdm`:
`1%|          | 436/69768 [01:04<2:42:39,  7.10it/s]`

Is there an elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that the matrix is a CSR you can try to create a sparse dataframe directly:

```
pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(data_transformed)
```

see documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html#migrating)

Comment: I tried it, but the last line never gets to execute:



```
df_sparse = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(data_transformed)

df_sparse_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_sparse)

df_sparse_spark.limit(2).toPandas()

```

sorry, not sure how to format code in comments...

Comment: So, you are able to create a sparse dataframe but you cannot convert it to spark, correct?

Comment: In fact no, I was testing on a small subset. Now I'm failing to create a pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix by memory (32gb driver) :(